# Issue in React, Redux and Typescript issue

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I'm new to Redux and Typescript

I got the below issue in my App.tsx file

```
webpack compiled with 1 warning
ERROR in src/App.tsx:12:14
TS2345: Argument of type '(didspatch: Dispatch<Action>) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyAction'.
  Property 'type' is missing in type '(didspatch: Dispatch<Action>) => Promise<void>' but required in type 'AnyAction'.
    10 |
    11 |   useEffect(()=>{
  > 12 |     dispatch(artistsActions.getArtistes());
       |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    13 |   },[])
    14 |
    15 |   const {loading, error, data} = useSelector((state) => state.artists);
```

App.tsx code

```
useEffect(()=>{
    dispatch(artistsActions.getArtistes());
},[])
```

Below is the action creator function

```
    export const getArtistes = () => async (dispatch: Dispatch<Action>)=> {
    try{
        dispatch({
            type: ActionType.GET_ARTIST_REQUEST
        });

        const {data} = await axios.get<Artists[]>(<API URL>);

        dispatch({
            type: ActionType.GET_ARTIST_SUCCESS,
            payload: data,
        });
    } catch(error: any) {
        dispatch({
            type:ActionType.GET_ARTIST_FAIL,
            payload: error.message
        })
    }
}
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: can you provide the code for `artistsActions.getArtistes()`?

Comment: @Undo Code added

Comment: I don't understand. `dispatch` is supposed to dispatch something; `getArtists()` doesn't return anything, and calling something `didspatch` makes it even more confusing.

Comment: @DaveNewton Sorry my bad, Typo error. But still the issue is there :(

Comment: `dispatch` _dispatches an action_. In your code there is no action to dispatch, it doesn't return anything for `dispatch` to dispatch. Instead it does its own dispatching. I'm not sure how else to explain it.

Answer (score 1):

The root of the problem you're currently having is you're calling `dispatch` inside of the `useEffect` with nothing (the result of `getArtistes` returns `void`.

So, to fix that type error, change `getArtistes` to `return` an object and *not* dispatch anything (i.e., in the places where you're `dispatch`ing you should just `return { type: ActionType.GET_ARTIST ... }`

That said, you have more issues.

You need to understand asynchronous requests with REDUX. Your `getArtistes` method first dispatches some action, starts an async request, and then dispatches another action. In reality, you should look into [Saga's](https://redux-saga.js.org/) or [Thunks](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk)

This may end up looking something like this:

App.tsx

```
useEffect(()=>{
  dispatch({ type: 'GET_ARTISTS_REQUESTED' });
},[])
```

```
function* fetchArtistes(action) {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.get<Artists[]>(<API URL>);

    yield put({
      type: 'GET_ARTIST_SUCCESS',
      payload: data,
    });
  } catch (e) {
    yield put({ type: 'GET_ARTIST_FAIL', payload: e.message });
  }
}

function* mySaga() {
  yield takeEvery("GET_ARTISTS_REQUESTED", fetchArtistes);
}
```